# Custom Django management command

Tags: python, django

The idea is to delete an object by accepting command line options:

- object can be deleted by ID and
- by date range

Expected behavior, new custom command call using:

```
python manage.py delete_obj --delete id 1234
```

or

```
python manage.py delete_obj --delete from 2019/10/01 to 2019/12/12
```

Code for the first part:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from ...models import SomeObject

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('id', type=int)

        parser.add_argument(
            '--delete',
            default = False,
            help='Delete product',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        if options['delete']:
            if options['id']:

                SomeObject.delete()
```

I add a custom option in the add_arguments() method for id. How can I define that object to be deleted by ID or by DATE RANGE?

Comment: The `from` `2019/10/01`, etc. are all seen as positional parameters.

Comment: `parser.add_argument('--from', ...)` with type=date if that's possible (and maybe a default)  Analogously, `--to`. I'd prefer `--before` `--after` or `--since` for dates, `--from` and `--to` are too often used for source and destination files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--id', type=int)
        parser.add_argument('--date_from')
        parser.add_argument('--date_to')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options['id']:
            try:
                instance = SampleModel.objects.get(id=options['id'])
                instance.delete()
                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Object Deleted'))
            except SampleModel.DoesNotExist:
                self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('Object not found'))
        elif options['date_from'] and options['date_to']:
            date_range = [options['date_from'], options['date_to']]
            SampleModel.objects.filter(datetime_field__range=date_range).delete()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Objects Deleted'))
        else:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('options are not given'))
```

**Usage:**

```
python manage.py command_name --id 123
python manage.py command_name --date_from 2012-12-12 --date_to 2013-12-12
```

---

The basic idea is, you can pass ***any number of arguments to your Django command***, and Django is able to ***typecast the input value to any native Python data type***.

Comment: thanks for your effort it's really close to what I am looking for ! Is it possible to have command line like :python manage.py delete_obj --delete from 2019/10/01 to 2019/12/12?

Comment: Since your command (`delete_obj`) is self-explanatory you don't need to add **`--delete`** flag.

Comment: The basic idea is, you can pass any number of arguments to your Django command, and you can Django is able to typecast the input value to any ***native python data type***